# how to write multiline in layout or Button?

Tags: xml, android-layout, layout

[how to different textsize and different text colour and write multiline in text view in below image in android?

[image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6oNsI.jpg)

am writing the following design,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/milk"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    tools:context="com.example.hussain.mytype2screen.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:id="@+id/txt1"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/Arrow"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/menu"
        android:padding="8dp"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/txt1"
        android:id="@+id/line1">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tx1"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:text="@string/stylish_text"
            style="@style/CustomText1"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tx2"
            style="@style/CustomText1"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tx1" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tx3"
            style="@style/CustomText1"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tx2"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tx4"
            style="@style/CustomText1"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tx3"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tx5"
            style="@style/CustomText1"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tx4"/>


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tx6"
            style="@style/CustomText2"
            android:layout_below="@id/tx1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tx7"
            style="@style/CustomText2"
            android:layout_below="@id/tx2"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tx6"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tx8"
            style="@style/CustomText2"
            android:layout_below="@id/tx3"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tx7"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tx9"
            style="@style/CustomText2"
            android:layout_below="@id/tx4"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tx8"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tx10"
            style="@style/CustomText2"
            android:layout_below="@id/tx5"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tx9"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

please give the solution for the above image..

Answer (score 0):

To change the font colour

```
android:textColor="#aaaaaa"
```

To change font Size e.g

```
 android:textSize="10sp"
```

it is recommended to use sp for text

if you want to write some text in more then one line using single TextView use "\n" , new line character

Comment: 1  for Yellow colour and next text colour in white so different text size and different text colour in same text view..

Comment: you cannot do it like this. create different Text View according to your requirement and assign colour and text Size to every Text View .

Answer (score 0):

If you want TextView to have some text with different text color, size, style and bold for multiple words in the same text view, use this approach

In strings.xml, add this

```
<resources>
    <string name="some_text"><font size="25" fgcolor="white"><b>FIRST BALL</b></font> <font size="18" fgcolor="red">ONE WINNING NUMBER</font></string>
</resources>
```

and in TextView add this property

```
android:text="@string/some_text"
```

and for showings multi lines just adjust the width like

```
android:layout_width="150dp"
```

Still if you are unable to achieve the requirement, It is recommended to use multiple textviews

Hope this helps.

Comment: "1 for Yellow colour and next text colour in white so different text size and different text colour in same text view.. " ---> this is your comment for above solution given by Nouman Shah, so my answer will work if you want different text size and different text color in same text view.